# Convert Object to json in iOS

Tags: ios, json

I have this object:

```
@interface EmailToSend : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *Subject;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *Body;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *Cc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *Bcc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *To;
@property (strong, nonatomic) EmailAddress *From;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *Username;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *Password;

@end

Bcc, To, From as Array EmailAdress

@interface EmailAddress : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int Id;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *address;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *displayName;

@end
```

I use the JSON framework in iOS to parse object `EmailToSend`:

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:emailToSend options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
 NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When I run the project, one error appears:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
(EmailToSend)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It says it all in the error message: `Invalid type in JSON write (EmailToSend)`. This is probably one of your own classes.

Comment: @NhuHow you have solved this problem, i am facing the same.

Answer (score 3):

`EmailToSend` is a class type that you use in your application. However, the built-in JSON serializer in Cocoa can only work with simple types such as `NSString` `NSArray` etc. You will have to make you `From` property a string if you want it to work.

And as pointed out by Wain in his comment, the root element also needs to be an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Comment: The root element should be a dictionary or an array.